# What is the difference between connect database_name and use database_name

Tags: mysql

I gone through some simple sql command in mysql
"connect databasename" and "use database"
As of my understanding it seems both same... 
[please see the snapshot:--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcIce.png)

i'm pretty much sure that i would get best answer here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You have a connection to a server, not a database. You can `USE` away all you want. The fact that you can start with a used db (the defaulted one to start) is window dressing. In mysql a schema and db are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect databasename gives you the Connection Information. like Connection id and actual used database.

use databasename changes the database to databasename

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html):

> The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as
>   the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database
>   remains the default until the end of the session or another USE
>   statement is issued:

Answer (score 0):

Google for SCHEMA. There is a difference between DATABASE and SCHEMA. You connect to a database and you use a SCHEMA.

Comment: as it relates to mysql what is difference between database and schema?

Comment: especially because the syntax (synonym) of `create schema myDb` is valid